# Link to different page after validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code for a registration page. I wonder how to link to another page after the form validation function?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function formValidator()
        {

            var position=document.getElementById("position");

                if(madeSelection(position,"chose a position"))
                {
                        {
                            alert("Correct");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                        return false;


                }



    function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg)
    {
        if(elem.value == "-------")
        {
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if (elem.value == "student")
        {
                 window.location.href="http://www.newpage.com";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
                 window.location.href="http://www.newpage.com"; 
            return true;
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form onsubmit="return formValidator()" method="get">
    <p> I'm a : 
    <select id="position">
        <option>-------</option>
      <option>Student  </option>
```

- // if select student it will go to student registration page

  ```
    <option>Lecturer</option>
  ```
- // if select this is will go to the validation and then link to
  lecturer registration page..but HOW?

  ```
  </select></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />    
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function formValidator()
        {

            var position=document.getElementById("position");

                if(madeSelection(position,"chose a position"))
                {
                        {
                            alert("Correct");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                        return false;


                }



    function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg)
    {
        if(elem.value == "-------")
        {
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if (elem.value == "student")
        {
                 window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
            return true;
        }
        else if (elem.value == "lecturer")
        {
                 window.location.href="http://www.bing.com";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
                 window.location.href="http://www.newpage.com"; 
            return true;
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form onsubmit="return formValidator()" method="get">
    <p> I'm a : 
    <select id="position">
        <option>-------</option>
      <option value="student">Student</option>
       <option value="lecturer">Lecturer</option>  
       </select></p>
<input type="submit" value="Next" />    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still the same, it can't link to other page after selected student or lecturer. i will only show correct

Comment: On my computer it's works fine. You can try to change "return true;" to "return false;" in madeSelection() function.

Comment: you meant in the else if there

Comment: works when I change the file name to html instead of html .. but why?

Comment: You can do easy by links: `<a href="http://google.com">Student</a> OR <a href="http://bing.com">Lecturer</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this:
window.location.assign('somepage.php');
```

Comment: Cannot work... it will just show"correct" after i click either student or lecturer

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="choose" id="student">student</br>
<input type="radio" name="choose" id="lecturer">lecturer</br>

<button onclick="doit()">click here</button>


<script>
function doit(){
var rad1 = document.getElementById("student");
var rad2 = document.getElementById("lecturer");

if(rad1.checked){
    window.location.assign('test1.php');
}
else if(rad2.checked){
    window.location.assign('test2.php');
}
else{
    window.load();
}


}
</script>
```